# why does my code receives an " Unexpected end of file"?

Tags: assembly, tasm

the code has an error of unexpected end of file and i cant seems to understand what's wrong can you please help me with this one?

```
;'--------------------------------

.MODEL small

.STACK

.DATA

LengthOfStr EQU 38

Handle DW ? ; to store file handle

FileName DB "C:\EXP6_FOLDER\test.txt",0 ; file to be opened

OpenError DB "An error has occured(opening)!$"

ReadError DB "An error has occured(reading)!$"

Buffer DB 100 dup (?) ; buffer to store data

.CODE

main proc far

mov ax, @data ; set up ds to be equal to the

mov ds, ax ; data segment

mov dx, OFFSET FileName ; put address of filename in dx

mov al, 2 ; access mode - read and write

mov ah, 3Dh ; function 3Dh -open a file

int 21h ; call DOS service

mov Handle, ax ; save file handle for later

jc ErrorOpening ; jump if carry flag set - error!

mov dx, offset Buffer ; address of buffer in dx

mov bx, Handle ; handle in bx

mov cx, 100 ; amount of bytes to be read

mov ah, 3Fh ; function 3Fh - read from file

int 21h ; call dos service

jc ErrorReading ; jump if carry flag set - error!

mov bx, Handle ; put file handle in bx


mov ah, 3Eh ; function 3Eh - close a file

int 21h ; call DOS service

mov cx, LengthOfStr ; length of string

mov si, OFFSET Buffer ; DS:SI - address of string

xor bh, bh ; video page - 0

mov ah, 0Eh ; function 0Eh - write character

NextChar:

lodsb ; AL = next character in string

int 10h ; call BIOS service

loop NextChar

mov ax, 4C00h ; terminate program

int 21h

ErrorOpening:

mov dx, offset OpenError ; display an error

mov ah, 09h ; using function 09h

int 21h ; call DOS service

mov ax, 4C01h ; end program with an errorlevel =1
int 21h


ErrorReading:

mov dx, offset ReadError ; display an error

mov ah, 09h ; using function 09h

int 21h ; call DOS service

mov ax, 4C02h ; end program with an errorlevel =2

int 21h


main endp
end main
```

Comment: What assembler, MASM or TASM?  Have you tried removing the comment line with the single quote at the top, in case somehow mismatched quotes are a problem even in comments?

Comment: im using tasm, yes did, still gives me an error of unexpected end of file.

Comment: Maybe add a blank line at the end of the file?

Comment: i did this, the code has 52 line then it gives me an error at line 53 saying unexpected end of file

Comment: Well, "Unexpected end of file" suggests that it didn't find the `END` directive.  I might try deleting lines until I figured out what was interfering with tasm finding it.  Maybe start with a 1 line file that's just `END`?  Then add stuff back until it breaks.  I don't think it's supposed to be case sensitive, but try that too.

Comment: ok i'll try this one thank you so much! gonna update here whats gonna happen. thank you :))